# How GridLayout works when specifying the columnspan and rowspan

Tags: android, xml, android-gridlayout

I have made a layout desing for my listview in an Android project. It's like that;

[image]

I have read and researched on other gridlayout samples and I have written this xml in accordance with I have got.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:columnCount="30"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout_notification">

    <com.ei.dizitakip.android.CircledNetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/fancy_notification_thumbnail"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:layout_rowSpan="6"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnSpan="25"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/fancy_title"
        android:textColor="@color/color_primary_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:id="@+id/fancy_season_icon"
        android:src="@mipmap/season_icon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnSpan="10"
        android:id="@+id/fancy_status_text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:id="@+id/fancy_domain_icon"
        android:src="@mipmap/www_icon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnSpan="11"
        android:id="@+id/fancy_domain_text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</GridLayout>
```

As you have realized that the code is far from the design. What am I missing about GridLayouts? This is the first time I have been used it and I used the same approach with LinearLayout's layout_weight. Really appreciated any code samples, approach or technique.

Comment: Specify your question. Consider your layout as a table. With columnspan you tell the layout how many columns the view element should take to be displayed, with rowspan you define how many rows the view should take in your table.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking with the same way. But, it doesn't work with the same way I think :) I don't understand, maybe the grids don't have equal size. Could you provide any sample like in the example above?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn´t work"? Basically it works. In order to get the design like it´s in your pic, you have to specify some margins and paddings, especially the left image should have "android:layout_gravity="center""

Comment: Well, it works but the result is not the result I want. Left Image covers all of the screen and the other elements are not visible. layout_gravity is used almost by almost every gridlayout. What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use android:layout_gravity to specify the size of a grid. This is an example from the Android Developers Blog

To achieve this design;

[image]

code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

        android:columnCount="4"
        >

    <TextView
            android:text="Email setup"
            android:textSize="32dip"

            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="You can configure email in just a few steps:"
            android:textSize="16dip"

            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Email address:"

            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    <EditText
            android:ems="10"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Password:"

            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    <EditText
            android:ems="8"
            />

    <Space
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />

    <Button
            android:text="Next"

            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="3"
            />
</GridLayout>
```

You need the use `<Space>` tag as well to achieve your design.